# Count occurence of 'x' above location of 'y' in a table (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to pull in data from a page (it's internal so the link wont work outside my organisation.) What I need to do is import the table up to the point that my unique criteria (from user input) is found in a row.

```
import requests

caseref = input('Case Ref:')

url = 'http://dfu-display/tv'
page = requests.get(url)
#print (page.status_code) SHOWS RESULT OF REQUEST IF FAILS EDIT THIS IN

from bs4 import beautifulsoup

soup = beautifulsoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
#print(soup.prettify())

for row in soup.findAll('table')[0].tbody.findAll('tr'):
    first_column = row.findAll()[0].contents
    second_column = row.findAll()[1].contents
    print (first_column)
    print (second_column)
```

The data in column 1 is always a unique reference number, column 2 is the person the task is allocated to.  I need to some how find a point in column 1 (caseref from user input) and then count the number of times the user above this is 'unallocated'

If possible I would like to stop parsing the table once the user input is found as this would speed up the code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, the first task is to find where the unique reference number occurs in column1.

```
urn = input("Unique Reference Number: ")
location = column1.index(urn)
```

Then you want to find all the occurrences of the name immediately before that location (i.e. `location-1`) so that you can count those occurrences. Start by slicing the list and getting the name to count.

```
names_to_search = column2[:location]
search_name = names_to_count_through[-1]
```

Now we can filter the names in the search list and check the length of that to know how many times `search_name` occurred up to that point.

```
names_to_count = filter(lambda n: n == search_name, names_to_search)
occurrences = len(list(names_to_count))  # list to force evaluation of filter
other_people = len(names_to_search) - occurrences
```